# Parsing Json output

Tags: python, json, parsing

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import json

url = "http://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/EUR.json?key=myapikey"


url = urllib.urlopen(url)
result = url.read()
url.close()
result = json.loads(result)


str(result)
```

this is the output 
{u'target': u'EUR', u'success': True, u'amount': 0.74, u'source': u'USD', u'rate': 0.7359, u'message': u''}

How can I strip just the Euro and the amount.  I saw some example  thanks

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the output of running that program? You seem to be missing a `print` statement.

Comment: This is a dict. If you don't know how to access elements of a dict you need to go and do a basic Python tutorial, since dicts are absolutely fundamental to Python.

Comment: [Here's the official Python tutorial, in case you need one.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Comment: Dictionaries, ok Cool  if that is the direction to take I will take it!

Answer (score 1):

Result is python `Dictionary`. Just use this syntax:

```
print result["target"], result["amount"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a dictionary. A dictionary holds pairs of keys and values, the values can be accessed by `result[key]`. For example:

```
print(result['target']) # EUR 
print(result['amount']) # 0.74
```

[This](http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/) seems to be a decent tutorial on lists, tuples and dictionaries.